# amixer sset 'Master' 50% works on terminal but not as os.system command

Tags: raspbian, audio, raspi-config, alsa, pulseaudio

I'm trying to write a python program on my Raspberry Pi to mute/change the volume of the speaker output as soon as it runs. If I type:

```
amixer sset 'Master' 50%
```

on the terminal, the volume is increased by 50%.

However if I write a python file called `filename.py` with the following lines:

```
import os
os.system("amixer sset 'Master' 50%")
```

and run it in terminal with

```
sudo python filename.py
```

it comes up with an error

```
amixer: Unable to find simple control 'Master',0
```

How can I just run exactly the same command in terminal as I do in python?

Comment: os.system(...) takes a [string as an argument](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system). You probably meant to write `os.system("amixer sset 'Master' 50%")`

Comment: Sorry thats what I meant. I edited the post, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Why do you call `sudo python filename.py` instead of just `python filename.py`? You don't seem to need sudo with `amixer`?

Comment: Wow! such a simple solution and its worked! Ive been trying all sorts of complicated solutions. Thanks MadMike, Im new the the forum, how can I rate this comment up?

Comment: I'm going to formulate it as a answer. I may then click the check-mark on the left to accept it.

Comment: *You* may then click the check-mark.. oh, bugger :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `filename.py` from

```
import os
os.system(amixer sset 'Master' 50%)
```

to

```
import os
os.system("amixer sset 'Master' 50%")
```

as [os.system(...)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) only accepts a [string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) as a argument.

## Additional points:

- Don't call `sudo python filename.py` if your program don't need root rights. In your case `python filename.py` should suffice.
- It's good form to add `#!/usr/bin/python` to the beginning of your script. This indicates it's a python script. So your file will looks like this:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/python

  import os
  os.system("amixer sset 'Master' 50%")
  ```